# Neo4j : (weakly) connected components algorithm, select only one component

Tags: neo4j

I looked how my data is connected in my database in Neo4j.

I want to keep only the most connected component (size of 2170 in the picture above).

My data has two types of nodes and only one type of relationship.

How can I select only the big component ?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by keep? Delete all the other nodes? Or have a graph projected with only the biggesrlt component?

Comment: I would like to have a graph projected with the biggest component in order to apply the label propagation algorithm. I don't know if it is a good method

Comment: Yea thats a good approach

Comment: Thank you, how can I do to filter the result of wcc ? I have only one relationship type

Answer (score 1):

So what you can do is to first write back the results of the wcc algorithm. An example would be:

```
CALL gds.wcc.write('lpa_test', {writeProperty:'wccComponents'})
```

And then run the LPA algorithm with cypher projections:

```
CALL gds.labelPropagation.stream({
    nodeQuery:"MATCH (n:Character) WHERE n.familyComponent = 0
               RETURN id(n) as id",
    relationshipQuery:"MATCH (s:Character)-->(t:Character)
                       RETURN id(s) as source, id(t) as target",
    validateRelationships:false})
YIELD nodeId, communityId
RETURN nodeId, communityId
```

Obviously your `nodeQuery` and `relationshipQuery` inputs would be a bit different as you probably have a different graph schema, but I hope you get the point.

I did something very similar in my [blog post](https://towardsdatascience.com/lord-of-the-wiki-ring-importing-wikidata-into-neo4j-and-analyzing-family-trees-da27f64d675e), only that I run the betweenness centrality algorithm on the largest component.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going to try it and I'll read the link on your blog

Comment: Hello Tomaž, I tried it but it didn't work.

My data look like this : (a:ARTICLE)<-['APPEARS_IN']-(k:KEYWORD)-['APPEARS_IN']->(a:ARTICLE)

It is a big network. The relationship has the weight property and some articles has labels. 

I would like to propagate this labels through the network with seed labels et weight properties. 

I tried it since yesterday but I don't know how to do this.